# Lambda, adicionar novo item da lista MVC 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Eu tenho um modelo onde um **cliente** tem um ou muitos **Sitemas**, e um **Sistema** tem um ou muitos **Clientes**: `N:M`

Estou com um problema na hora de adicionar um novo `SISTEMA`, para meu `cliente`
Meu Modelo está assim:

```
public  class Cliente : Pessoa
{
 public virtual ICollection<TipoDeSistemas> TipoDeSistemas { get; set; }

 public void AdicionarSistema(TipoDeSistemas tipoDeSistemas)
   {
            TipoDeSistemas.Add(tipoDeSistemas);
   }
}
public class TipoDeSistemas
{
 public virtual ICollection<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }
{
```

Na minha camada de serviço eu faço assim:

```
public void adicionarSistema(ClienteViewModel cliente, List<Guid> tipoDeSistemasId)
{
  var c = _clienteRepositorio.BuscarPorId(cliente.ClienteId);
// c => é o cliente vindo do banco
 foreach (var sistema in tipoDeSistemasId)
 {
  var ts = _tipoDeSistemaRepositorio.BuscarPorId(sistema);
   c.AdicionarSistema(ts);
 }
_clienteRepositorio.Atualizar(c);
}
```

Não ta adicionando um novo sistema na tabela que recebe o `n:m`
Não sei se eu fiz errado o mapeamento..
Está assim:

```
 public class ClienteConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cliente>
 {
         public ClienteConfig()
        {
         HasMany(c => c.TipoDeSistemas)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.MapLeftKey("Cliente_ClienteId");
                    m.MapRightKey("TipoDeSistema_SitemaId");
                    m.ToTable("Sistema_Cliente");
                });
        }
 }
```

Eu alterei o mapeamento, e deixei assim, para ver se era isso:

```
  public class ClienteConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cliente>
    {
        public ClienteConfig()
        {
        HasMany(c => c.TipoDeSistemas)
                .WithMany(c => c.Cliente);
        }
    }
```

e fiz a mesma coisa na configuração do Sistema:

```
public class TipoDeSistemaConfig: EntityTypeConfiguration<TipoDeSistemas>
    {
        public TipoDeSistemaConfig()
        {

            HasMany(t => t.Cliente)
                .WithMany(t => t.TipoDeSistemas);
        }
    }
```

Mas ainda assim, continua não adicionando o(s) Sistema(s) para o cliente.
eu debuguei o código, e verifiquei, que no meu repositorio ta chegando o sistema adicionado `Cliente.TipoDeSistema.Count(1)`

o repositório Atulizar esta Assim:

```
public virtual void Atualizar(TEntidade obj)
        {
            var entry = Db.Entry(obj);
            DbSet.Attach(obj);
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            SaveChanges();
        }
```

ele passa por esse método normalmente, salva, e retorna, tudo que venha no `OBJ` atualiza, mas ele não adiciona o `sistema_cliente`, na tabela que recebe o `N:M`
Não da erro nenhum, mas tbm não salva no banco o(s) sistema(s) para o cliente.

Tentei usando DAO, e teóricamente, está dando certo.
estou inserindo direto na tabela que recebe o `N:M`
Não sei se é uma boa prática, mas momentaneamente resolveu o problema. já que usando entity não adicionava.

Class ClienteDAO:

```
 public void Inserir(Cliente cliente, TipoDeSistemas tipoDeSistemas)
        {
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();

            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comando.CommandText = "insert into ClienteTipoDeSistemas(Cliente_ClienteId, TipoDeSistemas_TipoDeSistemasId) values(@Cliente_ClienteId, @TipoDeSistemas_TipoDeSistemasId)";
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cliente_ClienteId",cliente.ClienteId);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipoDeSistemas_TipoDeSistemasId", tipoDeSistemas.TipoDeSistemasId);

            Conexao con = new Conexao();
            con.Crud(comando);
        }
```

Comment: Como assim não salva e não dá erro? não faltou um `SaveChanges()` no caminho?

Comment: eu editei a pergunta, e coloquei o método `ATUALIZAR`

Comment: Não entedi essa linha `entry.State = EntityState.Modified;`... nesse ponto se o state já não está como modified, já tem um problema. Algo errado com o seu mapping ou o com o seu método `AdicionarSistema()`

Comment: Não é essa parte não, pois eu tentei assim tbm `db.Entry(cs).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();` e mesmo assim não adiciona o sistema no cliente

Comment: Inclusive, eu retirei a responsabilidade de adicionar do método, e usei o `add` direto no service: `TipoDeSistemas ts = _tipoDeSistemaRepositorio.BuscarPorId(sistema);
                cliente.TipoDeSistemas.Add(ts);`